# Proper sscanf usage troubles

Tags: c, string, gcc, printf, scanf

I have a string stored in an array called `decrypted` as follows:

```
char decrypted[5000];
sprintf(decrypted,"%s","192.168.0.2<==>6060<==>this is ipsec data");
```

and I am trying to read this using sscanf as follows:

```
char ip_source[20];
int port_source;
char message[1000];

 sscanf(decrypted,"%s<==>%d<==>%s",ip_source,&port_source,message);
 printf("source = %s\nport = %d\nmessage = %s\n",ip_source,port_source,message);
```

but this doesn't seem to work as **I get the following output:**

```
source = 192.168.0.2<==>6060<==>this
port = 0
message =
```

What am I doing wrong? And how may I fix it ?

**EDIT:**

As per suggestions below, here is how I have changed the code and this is the new output:

```
char decrypted[5000];
sprintf(decrypted,"%s","192.168.0.2<==>6060<==>this is ipsec data");

char ip_source[20];
int port_source;
char message[1000];

 sscanf(decrypted,"%[^<]<==>%d<==>%s",ip_source,&port_source,message);

 printf("source = %s\nport = %d\nmessage = %s\n",ip_source,port_source,message);
```

**Output:**

```
source = 192.168.0.2
port = 6060
message = this
```

How do I make message be read as a full string and not stop at the first space ?

**EDIT 2:**

Can I indulge you good folks just a little further ?

Here is another string I am trying to read :

```
sprintf(decrypted,"%s","S=192.168.0.2|D=192.168.0.4||<==>S=6060");
sscanf(decrypted,"S=%s|D=%s||<==>S=%d",&ip_source,&ip_dest,&port_source);
```

Its again causing issues. I tried to impliment your solutions to try to fix it as follows:

sscanf(decrypted,"S=%[^<]<==>|D=%s||<==>S=%d",&ip_source,&ip_dest,&port_source);

but that didn't work.How to change above to fix it ?

Comment: I like how decrypted is 5000 large, but the scanned bits only sum up to a little above 1000. IT'S GODDAMN 2013. CAN WE PLEASE STOP TREATING BUFFER OVERRUNS WITH ANY DEGREE OF ACCEPTANCE WHATSOEVER?

Comment: "Can I indulge you good folks just a little further?" This is not a chat room, it's a Q&A site.

Comment: that was a question .. perhaps you didn't like my politeness before asking it. Well suit yourself . I appreciate your help anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sscanf(decrypted,"%s<==>%d<==>%s",ip_source,&port_source,message);
```

In `scanf`, `%s` consumes every character that is not considered a space by default. That's why you get `192.168.0.2<==>6060<==>this` in `source`.

You can fix this by changing what `scanf` considers a delimiter like this:

```
sscanf(decrypted,"%[^<]<==>%d<==>%s",ip_source,&port_source,message);
```

**EDIT:**

The same rule also applies for what is going to be stored in `message`. Assuming `message` can only contain characters in the set `a-z`, `A-Z`, and spaces, you might want to try this:

```
sscanf(decrypted,"%[^<]<==>%d<==>%[A-Za-z ]",ip_source,&port_source,message);
```

**EDIT2:**

For the other string, you can't use `[^<]`, because this time the delimiter is `|`. You should use this instead:

```
sscanf(decrypted,"S=%[^|]|D=%[^|]||<==>S=%d",ip_source,ip_dest,&port_source);
```

Also, `&ip_source` and `&ip_dest` would be wrong, since they are defined as character arrays - you don't need the reference operator.

Finally, **consider adding limits check to your buffer**, as stated in other answers:

```
sscanf(decrypted,"%19[^<]<==>%d<==>%999[a-z]",ip_source,&port_source,message);
```

The same goes for the second `scanf`.

Comment: Much obliged . Thank you

Comment: @sukhvir Since you accepted my answer, I also recommend you to use buffer limit checks, as suggested by dasblinkenlight. This is important, so I updated my answer with this information.

Comment: Thanks, I implimented the limit checks as well

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the first `%s` does not know where to stop. Replace with `%[^<]` to fix.

The other problem is that the `message` string will terminate early. Pick a character that is not allowed inside a message (say, `\n`), and use `%[^\n]` to read the message.

Finally, since you are reading into fixed buffers, apply the standard precaution, and tell `sscanf` how big your buffers are.

```
sscanf(decrypted, "%19[^<]<==>%d<==>%999[^\n]", ip_source, &port_source, message);
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/SnxxZv).

In general, if your string has a fixed delimiter `x`, use that delimiter in the `%[^x]` format specifier. So `"S=%s|D=%s||<==>S=%d"` format string becomes `"S=%19[^|]|D=%19[^|]||<==>S=%d"`

Comment: `%[%<]` is typo ? I think it is typo

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes, it was a typo. This is now fixed.

Comment: @sukhvir Take a look at the edit, it fixes the problem with the delimiters in the trailing portion of the input string.

Comment: +1 for [^#]. Nice one, I didn't catch the problem with message ending too early.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks that fixed it completely

Comment: This will still write past the end of `message`, so I'd be weary of calling it "fixed it completely".

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes This is now fixed - it will no longer write past the end of the buffer.